# Looking for a specific group set of magic boots

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items

I recall that one of the books of 4th Edition described two pairs of magic boots, who formed a group set together conferring bonuses to the wearers if both sets are worn. They had something to do with agility or jumping, but that's all I remember. And I cannot seem to remember which book this was: do any of you people know if this is an actual group magic item, and if so from which book?

Comment: Did both pairs have to be worn by the same person?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you might be thinking of Rash and Reckless, [an artifact](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=134) that is a pair of boots from DMG 2.

Description:

> History DC 22: Rash and Reckless are the individual names of two artifacts, each a pair of boots, meant to be worn by two allies. They originally belonged to a pair of scoundrels who spent their lives in revelry and adventure in the capital city of Nerath years ago. The artifacts allow their owners to work in concert to perform masterful feats of acrobatics and athleticism.
>
> History DC 27: The original owners of Rash and Reckless were an inseparable pair of adventurers who began their professional life as acrobats in a traveling carnival. They extended the acrobatic training, teamwork, and entertainer's panache that they learned from the sideshows to their adventuring career. Everything else about this duo's life is a matter of conjecture, legend, and tall tale. To this day, no one is sure of their gender or race, where they were born, or the details of their adventuring career. Even their names are lost to history, replaced by the names of the artifacts they left behind as their legacy.

Comment: +1 Didn't think to check DMG2. That sounds closer to what he's looking for.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for! The DMG isn't exactly the first place you go looking for when looking for magic items, so I forgot to look into that one. But thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're thinking of the Feystride Boots in Adventurer's Vault 2?

> Feystride Boots         Level 11
>   **Item Slot**: Feet          9,000gp
>   **Property**: While you have a drow or elf ally within 10 squares of you, the range of your *fey step* racial power increases by 2 squares.
>   **Power (Encounter, Teleportation):** Move Action. While you have an eladrin ally within 10 squares of you, you can expend your *elven accuracy* racial power or your use of the Lolthtouched racial trait to teleport 5 squares.

I didn't do an exhaustive search, but it looks like Item Sets (and Group Item Sets) were introduced in the Adventurer's Vault 2, and I don't see any of them in the other books I checked. The only boots on any of these group sets are the Feystride Boots.

The group set benefit for three wielders (ideally at least one Eladrin and at least one Elf or Drow) gives a +1 item bonus to speed.